# Laravel conditional relations with Entrust

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using Laravel4.2 with Entrust for managing Roles. A user can have either a client role or provider role. However, there are many things both Roles can do. To get their profiles, i use `$user->profile` but depending or role the profile will be fetched either from Client_profile or Provider_profile table. In the model i am using the following relation:

```
 public function profile() {
    if ($this->hasRole('User')) {
        return $this->hasOne('UserProfile');
    }
    elseif ($this->hasRole('Provider')) { 
        return $this->hasOne('ProviderProfile');
        }   
}
```

is this the right way? it works well for logged in user, but i cannot get profile of some other user by this approach.